# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 150 (PHP Version to new?)

Tags: php, themes

I have bought [this Theme on CodeCanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-php-live-blog/2576583) and would like to install it now, but the browser says that there is a unexpected end of file in index.php on line 150. The problem seems to be, that there is a condition regarding the php version. It should be 5.2.16 - I have 5.5 - is it to new or is there an other problem?

```
<?php
require_once "../config.php";
if(!defined('ROOT_PATH') || ROOT_PATH==''){
die(get_text("ROOT_PATH_NOT_SET"));
}
if(!file_exists(ROOT_PATH."/liveblog/install/handler.php")){
die(get_text("INVALID_ROOT_PATH"));
}
if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'/liveblog/db/live_blogs.db')){
die(get_text("ULB_ALREADY_INSTALLED"));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Ultimate Live Blog - <?=get_text("INSTALLATION")?></title>
<meta name="description" content="Live blogging made easy with Ultimate Live Blog"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfobject.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var readyToGo = false;
var connected = false;
 function throwResponse(desc, type){
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 600 );
if(type=='1'){
    var pid = 'err-mess';
    }else{
    var pid = 'ok-mess';
    }
$('.info-message').css("display", "block").attr('id', pid).children('p').html(desc);

}
function securityOkay(){
connected = true;
}
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#btn-install").click(function(){
    if($("#server").val()=='' || $("#devkey").val()=='' || $("#aname").val()=='' || $("#upass").val()=='' || $("#apassre").val()==''){

         throwResponse("<?=get_text("FILL_ALL_FIELDS")?>", 1);
    }else{
$.getJSON("handler.php?final="+connected+"&server="+encodeURIComponent($("#server").val())+"&devkey="+encodeURIComponent($("#devkey").val())+"&name="+encodeURIComponent($("#aname").val())+"&pass="+encodeURIComponent($("#apass").val())+"&repass="+encodeURIComponent($("#apassre").val()), function (data) {
   if (data.length != 0) {
        if (data[0]['error'] == undefined) {
        $('.info-message').css("display", "none");
        readyToGo = true;

        if(readyToGo && !connected){
        $("#p2p-object").slideDown();
           var flashvars = {
        stype: "install",
        server: $("#server").val(),
        devkey: $("#devkey").val()
    };
    var params = {
        menu: "false",
        scale: "noScale",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        wmode: "opaque"
    };
    var attributes = {
        id: "secAllow"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("../p2p.swf", "secAllow", "300", "150", "10", "http://<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/liveblog/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    }
    if(readyToGo && connected){
    $("#install-form").fadeOut(500);
    $("#install-note").fadeIn(200);
    throwResponse("<?=get_text("INSTALLED_SUCCESSFULLY")?>", 2);
    }
    }else{
        var tmp = data[0]['error'];
    throwResponse(tmp, 1);
    }
    }
    });
}

    });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="window">
<div class="header-title"><?=get_text("INSTALLATION")?></div>
<?php
 if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.2.16') >= 0) 
{
//that's ok
}
else 
{ 
$tmp = str_replace('<ver>', phpversion(), get_text("UNSUPPORTED_PHP_VERSION"));
$errors[] = $tmp; // 150th line!!!!!
}

?>
<?php if(!isset($errors)){?>
<div class="info-message" id="i-mess"><p><?=get_text("THANKS_FOR_BUYING")?></p></div>
<div id="install-form">
<p class="desc"><?=get_text("ADOBE_CIRRUS_SETTINGS")?> (<?=get_text("REFER_DOCUMENTATION")?>)</p>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("SERVER")?>:</span><input type="text" id="server" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("DEVKEY")?>:</span><input type="text" id="devkey" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<p class="desc"><?=get_text("SET_UP_ADMIN")?></p>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("USERNAME")?>:</span><input type="text" id="aname" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("PASSWORD")?>:</span><input type="password" id="apass" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("CONFIRM_PASSWORD")?>:</span><input type="password" id="apassre" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div id="p2p-object" style="display:none;">
<p class="desc"><?=get_text("P2P_CLICK_ALLOW")?></p>
<div style="width:300px;margin:0px auto;">
<div id="secAllow" style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;" name="secAllow"><p>
<?php
$tmp = str_replace('<url>', '<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" target="_blank">', get_text("NEED_UPDATE_FLASH_PLAYER"));
$tmp = str_replace('</url>', '</a>', $tmp);
echo $tmp;
?>
</p></div>
</div></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="btn-install"><?=get_text("INSTALL")?></a>
</div>
<div id="install-note">
<h1><?=get_text("READY_TO_GO")?></h1>
<p><?php
$tmp = str_replace('<url>', '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/liveblog/panel">', get_text("INSTALLED_TEXT"));
$tmp = str_replace('</url>', '</a>', $tmp);
echo $tmp;
?></p>
</div>
<? }else{
foreach($errors as $mess){
echo '<div class="info-message" id="err-mess" style="margin:15px auto;"><p>'.$mess.'</p></div>';
}
echo '<p class="desc">'.get_text("CORRECT_ERRORS_THEN_RELOAD").'</p>';
} ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which one is your `150`th line?

Comment: This usually indicates you're missing a closing curly brace somewhere. Check all your braces are closed properly.

Comment: I added a comment on the 150th line now. Yes I checked it, but I don´t see anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in line 141

```
<? }else{
```

into

```
<?php }else{
```

because probably in your configuration you don't have short tags enabled

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    require_once "../config.php";
    if(!defined('ROOT_PATH') || ROOT_PATH==''){
        die(get_text("ROOT_PATH_NOT_SET"));
    }
    if(!file_exists(ROOT_PATH."/liveblog/install/handler.php")){
        die(get_text("INVALID_ROOT_PATH"));
    }
    if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'/liveblog/db/live_blogs.db')){
        die(get_text("ULB_ALREADY_INSTALLED"));
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Ultimate Live Blog - <?=get_text("INSTALLATION")?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Live blogging made easy with Ultimate Live Blog"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var readyToGo = false;
        var connected = false;
        function throwResponse(desc, type){
            $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 600 );
            if(type=='1'){
                var pid = 'err-mess';
            }
            else{
                var pid = 'ok-mess';
            }
            $('.info-message').css("display", "block").attr('id', pid).children('p').html(desc);
        }
        function securityOkay(){
            connected = true;
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn-install").click(function(){
                if($("#server").val()=='' || $("#devkey").val()=='' || $("#aname").val()=='' || $("#upass").val()=='' || $("#apassre").val()==''){

                    throwResponse("<?=get_text("FILL_ALL_FIELDS")?>", 1);
                }
                else{
                    $.getJSON("handler.php?final="+connected+"&server="+encodeURIComponent($("#server").val())+"&devkey="+encodeURIComponent($("#devkey").val())+"&name="+encodeURIComponent($("#aname").val())+"&pass="+encodeURIComponent($("#apass").val())+"&repass="+encodeURIComponent($("#apassre").val()), function (data) {
                        if (data.length != 0) {
                            if (data[0]['error'] == undefined) {
                                $('.info-message').css("display", "none");
                                readyToGo = true;

                                if(readyToGo && !connected){
                                    $("#p2p-object").slideDown();
                                    var flashvars = {
                                            stype: "install",
                                            server: $("#server").val(),
                                            devkey: $("#devkey").val()
                                        };
                                    var params = {
                                            menu: "false",
                                            scale: "noScale",
                                            allowScriptAccess: "always",
                                            wmode: "opaque"
                                        };
                                    var attributes = {
                                            id: "secAllow"
                                        };
                                    swfobject.embedSWF("../p2p.swf", "secAllow", "300", "150", "10", "http://<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/liveblog/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
                                }
                                if(readyToGo && connected){
                                    $("#install-form").fadeOut(500);
                                    $("#install-note").fadeIn(200);
                                    throwResponse("<?=get_text("INSTALLED_SUCCESSFULLY")?>", 2);
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                var tmp = data[0]['error'];
                                throwResponse(tmp, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="window">
<div class="header-title"><?=get_text("INSTALLATION")?></div>
<?php
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.2.16') <= 0) {
         $tmp = str_replace('<ver>', phpversion(), get_text("UNSUPPORTED_PHP_VERSION"));
         $errors[] = $tmp; // 150th line!!!!!
    }
?>
<?php 
    if(!isset($errors)){
?>
<div class="info-message" id="i-mess"><p><?=get_text("THANKS_FOR_BUYING")?></p></div>
<div id="install-form">
<p class="desc"><?=get_text("ADOBE_CIRRUS_SETTINGS")?> (<?=get_text("REFER_DOCUMENTATION")?>)</p>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("SERVER")?>:</span><input type="text" id="server" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("DEVKEY")?>:</span><input type="text" id="devkey" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<p class="desc"><?=get_text("SET_UP_ADMIN")?></p>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("USERNAME")?>:</span><input type="text" id="aname" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("PASSWORD")?>:</span><input type="password" id="apass" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div class="field-section"><span><?=get_text("CONFIRM_PASSWORD")?>:</span><input type="password" id="apassre" class="text-input" style="float:left;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<div id="p2p-object" style="display:none;">
<p class="desc"><?=get_text("P2P_CLICK_ALLOW")?></p>
<div style="width:300px;margin:0px auto;">
<div id="secAllow" style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;" name="secAllow"><p>
<?php
    $tmp = str_replace('<url>', '<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" target="_blank">', get_text("NEED_UPDATE_FLASH_PLAYER"));
    $tmp = str_replace('</url>', '</a>', $tmp);
    echo $tmp;
?>
</p></div>
</div></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="btn-install"><?=get_text("INSTALL")?></a>
</div>
<div id="install-note">
<h1><?=get_text("READY_TO_GO")?></h1>
<p><?php
$tmp = str_replace('<url>', '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/liveblog/panel">', get_text("INSTALLED_TEXT"));
$tmp = str_replace('</url>', '</a>', $tmp);
echo $tmp;
?>
</p>
</div>
<?php 
}
else{
    foreach($errors as $mess){
        echo '<div class="info-message" id="err-mess" style="margin:15px auto;"><p>'.$mess.'</p></div>';
    }
    echo '<p class="desc">'.get_text("CORRECT_ERRORS_THEN_RELOAD").'</p>';
} 
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```